# Linking separate images into separate html pages using xsl

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am busy with a college project that has an XML with a bunch of bands. I have currently got my XSL to output more than one HTML pages that act as a "profile page" for each band (so each band is on a seperate HTML page) with links linking to one another. Now, I want to add an image of the band on the corresponding html page. Is this possible?

Here is an example of one artist in the XML:

```
<lineup>
  <artist id="101">
    <name>Jeremey Loops</name>
    <genres>
      <genre>Acoustic</genre>
    </genres>
    <writeup>
      Jeremy Loops aint no traditional 'band', creating music on the spot with     that there loopdaloop pedal. Various artists also join him for free jam sessions     & the music they create is all original. it'll definitely make ya dance like a hick!
    </writeup>
    <gig>
      <day>FRIDAY</day>
      <time>
        <starts>12:00</starts>
        <ends>14:00</ends>
      </time>
    </gig>
  </artist>
</lineup>
```

Here is what I have tried with the XSL but only to find that the image shows on all the pages with 'true' and 'false' written on both sides of the image.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" name="html"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="lineup"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="lineup">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="artist"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="artist">

<xsl:variable name="filename" select="concat('bands/',name,'.html')" />
<xsl:value-of select="$filename" />  
<xsl:result-document href="{$filename}" format="html">
    <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../sass/test.css" />
        <title>
            <!-- TITLE OF PAGE -->
            Band - <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
<!-- Adding Image -->
<div class="images">
                <xsl:value-of select="name = 'Jeremey Loops'"/>
                    <img src="images/jeremey_loops.png" alt="Jeremey Loops standing with guitar" height="350px"/>
            </div>

<!-- LINKS TO BAND PAGES -->
        <div class="box links">
            <xsl:variable name="current" select="@id" />
            <xsl:for-each select="/lineup/artist" >
                <a href="{name}.html">
                    <xsl:value-of select="name"/> | 
                </a>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
</xsl:result-document>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So all I want is 'Jeremey Loops' image to show on his page and not on the other artists' pages and the same goes for the rest. Should I add a filter for every artist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a function translating the artist into an image url.

Say you have a directory "images" with images whose filename format follows a pattern `{artist_id}_{lowercase_underscored_name}.png`:

```
101_jeremy_loops.png
32_phil_beats.png
420_snoop_dogg.png
...
```

You could then write an XSLT function (or a similar named template if you're stuck with XSLT 1.0) that creates the file path from given parameters:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:foo="http://whatever">

<!-- foo:getImgUrl("64","Phil Beats") -> "64_phil_beats.png" -->
<xsl:function name="foo:getImgUrl">
    <xsl:param name="artist_id"/>
    <xsl:param name="artist_name"/>

    <xsl:value-of select="$artist_id"/>
    <xsl:text>_</xsl:text>

    <!-- returns lowercased artist name, replaces all non-alphanumerical
         characters with underscores. -->
    <xsl:value-of select="replace(lower-case($artist_name),'[^a-z0-9]','_')"/>

    <xsl:text>.png</xsl:text>
</xsl:function>

...
```

Use it in your stylesheet like so:

```
...
<img>
    <xsl:attriute name="src">
        <xsl:value-of select="foo:getImgUrl(@id, name/text())"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</img>
...
```

Comment: What does the '\P{NL}' mean? I am getting an error when I run it through Cygwin. " Syntax error at char 3 in regular expression: Unknown character category NL" @Peping

Comment: Ah, my bad, i've actually never dealt with regexes in xslt. I thought  '\P{NL}' would mean all characters except alphanumerical. Apparently, I can't read the docs and you need something more like '[^a-z0-9]'. I've edited the answer to reflect that. Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#charcter-classes

Comment: that seemed to have sorted it out. Now I just need to figure out where it is writing those files to so that I could rename or move my current images to that location! @peping